# Magento color swatches add pictures one time

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, color-swatches

I've just managed to get the default color swatche from Magento 1.9.1. working. Now I've noticed that for each product the swatches should be uploaded to the product images. Isn't it possible to upload them once foreach attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upload swatch images in the media gallery. The instructions are in the Magento docs:

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch-image-upload.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog%7CSwatches%7CPreparing%2520Swatch%2520Images%7C_____1

Comment: You're welcome:)